# How we can archive logs based on a period or size in log4net Table Appender?

Tags: azure, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender, log4net-filter

I am using Table Appender for logging. I would like to separate data between the period or size. How we can create a archive for logs if we are using Table Appender.

Comment: What do you mean with Table Appender? AdoNetAppender? And what do you mean with archive?

Comment: Log4Net Logging framework will provide the functionality to manage logs for all framework we are using Log4net frame work for logging errors into azure tabke storage. we have to use appender class for format the logging  errors and details.  https://github.com/zacg/log4net.Azure